# Java RESTful webservice, 404 not found

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I am creating a RESTful web service with jersey 2.0, here is my web.xml file:

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.shop.domain.ShoppingApplication
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My ShoppingApplication class:

```
public class ShoppingApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        s.add(CustomerResource.class);
        return s;
    }   
}
```

And my CustomerResource class:

```
@Path("/customers")
public class CustomerResource{

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getCustomer(){
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

When running with **localhost:8080/customers**, I got a 404 not found page, how should I fix it.

Comment: Does localhost:8080 work ? Go there and see which are your available resources (there has to be a GUI manager).

Comment: @powerMock hi, the glassfish server works.

Answer (score 0):

Using JAX-RS inside a non-JEE6 container requires you to provide a JAX-RS Servlet (like Jersey) to be mapped within your web.xml

Change your web.xml to

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.shop.domain.ShoppingApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    ...
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    ...
</web-app>
```

See https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet.2 for docs.

Comment: Hi, after changing the web.xml, I still got 404, it seems that the `<servlet></servlet>` field makes no sense, because no matter how to change it, it doesn't show error, but just give 404.

Comment: Keep in mind, localhost:8080/customers will work only if your app is deployed to the root context (ROOT.war). In every other case watch your context path(something like mayapp.war deploys to localhost:8080/myapp/...)